# How to get the updated selected item in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, performance

I had to refresh the items of a TreeView as some of the changes made were not reflected in the code behind. There are about 15 parent items and each parent has around 50 - 100 child items.

```
treeView.Items.Refresh();
treeview.UpdateLayout();
```

This is called every time a search is made on the tree (textbox search). 
Will it affect the performance?

EDIT :

I set the selected item of the tree in the ViewModel. Somehow for some cases(random), even after setting a new selected item, the change is not reflected in the view.

treeView.SelectedItem - remembers the previously selected item and returns the previous selection. It returns the new selection only if I call UpdateLayout() on the tree before I get the SelectedItem. This in turn affects the performance. What can I do to get the updated SelectedItem.

Comment: how are you binding the TreeView?

Comment: Read this : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.updatelayout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can give me an example that when should use UIElement.UpdateLayout()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9908691/can-give-me-an-example-that-when-should-use-uielement-updatelayout)

Comment: @azemia The treeView items are bound an observable collection.

Comment: @AmolBavannavar My question was about the performance. One of the answers in the link you sent does answer this particular question. Thanks anyways.

Comment: I would suggest you use CollectionViewSource to bind to the treeview. You can find information at http://wpftutorial.net/DataViews.html

Comment: Your x-problem is *some of the changes made were not reflected in the code behind*. For as long as you not solving it directly you will have to apply workarounds like this one, which are always not optimal. So yes, it will affect performance.

Comment: You are right. Let me edit my question.